# jquery get the selected option of a dynamic select using select id

Tags: jquery

This is my select and i want using the below jquery code to read the selected option of a dynamic select id.

```
<select class="involved" data-id="<?= $id; ?>" id="involved_id<?= $id; ?>" name="involved_id<?= $id; ?>">
<option value="0"> select </option>.....
</select>
```

This is the jquery to run the php script after selection.
I tried eg to pass the id by  `$("select.involved"+id)` and `$("select.involved").attr("data-id")`but its not working

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
$("select.involved").change(function(){
    var selectedInvolved = $(".involved option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process-request.php",
        data: { involved : selectedInvolved } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
});
```

This is the div where the php script prints data.

```
<div class="response<?= $id; ?>" id="response">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of a different select than the one you got the `data-id` attribute from?

Comment: No. The select is in a while so i could be 1 to N

Comment: But what is `this` in `var id = $(this).attr("data-id");`?

Comment: What are you using that `id` variable for?

Comment: to get the select id

Comment: Which select id? Where does `this` come from? Is it inside another event handler?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another handler.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're really trying to do. Do you click on one element, get its `data-id`, and use that to get the value of another element with that ID?

Comment: i create the select using php and its in a while so i giveto it an id, if i get 3 results then i will have 3 selects. So what i want is to read the id (data-id) of the select i change and get its value

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a jQuery event handler, `this` contains the target element of the event. So use `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected option, and `$(this).data("id")` to get the value of its `data-id` attribute.

The assignment to `id` needs to be inside the `.change()` function (although it doesn't use that variable, so I'm not sure why you need it).

```js
$("select.involved").change(function() {
  var selectedInvolved = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process-request.php",
    data: {
      involved: selectedInvolved
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    $("#response").html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: i already tried that but it work only if the first select changes. this is what i need 
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$("select.involved"+id).change(function() {
var selectedInvolved = $(this).val();
.......
but i doesn't pass the data-id of select